# Picture size difference problem on Android and iOS

Tags: android, html, css, ios, reactjs

I'm trying to make a site. I added a picture. Later, when I viewed the site on both Android and IOS phones, I saw that the pictures behaved differently. Picture-1 is of Android Galaxy j-5 phone. Picture-2 belongs to the iOS iPhone-6s screen. I want it to look like the Android screen on the iOS screen. What do I need to fix.
This was the code I wrote.

**File.js**

```
import React from "react";
import "./style.css";
import image from "./../../../../commons/assets/images/circlecross.svg"

function HomeImageTwo({ info }) {
  return (
    <div
      style={{
        display: "flex",
        justifyContent: "center",
        margin: "0",
      }}
    >
      <img
        src={image}
        className="home-ImageTwo"
      ></img>
    </div>
  );
}

export { HomeImageTwo };
```

**style.css**

```
.home-ImageTwo {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  max-width: 2500px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .home-ImageTwo {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
  }
}
```

Picture-1[image]

Picture-2[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image isn't in background, so the back properties aren't necessary.

Instead, try `object-fit: cover;` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit)

And to be alright semantically speaking, consider replacing `div` by `figure`

Comment: Thank you so much. The problem is solved directly :)